# C++ copy constructor calling other constructors

Tags: c++

I have this code. I'm not that proficient in C++, so I'm going to ask several questions:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line {

   public:
      int getLength( void );
      Line( int len );             // simple constructor
      Line( const Line &obj);  // copy constructor
      ~Line();                     // destructor

   private:
      int *ptr;
};

// Member functions definitions including constructor
Line::Line(int len) {
   cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;

   // allocate memory for the pointer;
   ptr = new int;
   *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj) {
   cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
   ptr = new int;
   cout<<&obj<<endl;
   *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}

Line::~Line(void) {
   cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
   delete ptr;
}

int Line::getLength( void ) {
   return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj) {
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

// Main function for the program
int main() {

   int a = 10;
   cout<<&a<<endl;
   Line line(a);

   display(line);

   return 0;
}
```

1. Here I don't see where we call copy contructor.
2. Destructor is being called twice. Where is the second object is being created?
3. `Line::Line(const Line &obj)` receives address of `a` as a parameter? I guess not. But why? `a` by itself is not an instance of Line, so why function accepts that?
4. What would be the difference between `Line::Line(const Line &obj)` and `Line::Line(const Line obj)`
5. And could you please explain this `*ptr = *obj.ptr;` . From here i know only lhs, which dereferences ptr (aka sets value of an object). But I didn't get what's in rhs?

I'd appreciate if you explain with less technical terms and more examples, for clarity

Above code outputs this:

```
0x7fff692196a4
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
0x7fff69219698
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
```

Comment: So what is the output of this program? How did you figure out that default constructor is called if it is not implemented here? Destructor called for `line` `main` function local variable and for `obj` `display` function argument (which is copy-constructed).

Comment: You don't have a default constructor. Are you talking about `Line(int)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Editing

Comment: `Line line(a)` is calling the `int` constructor, that should be obvious.

Comment: You still haven't explained where you see a call to a default constructor. In any case, what you need is a [book for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241631).

Comment: No more default constructor in question. Updated it

Comment: @Yura Do you know what pass by value is?

Comment: There is also a thing called debugger that allows you to execute code line-by line and figure out what is called where.

Comment: @NathanOliver , yes, I know. But I still don't feel confident about it

Comment: @Yura `void display(Line obj)` accepts it's argument by copy. `obj` is a *copy* of the object given as the argument (`line` in this case).

Comment: @VTT , no all people smart enough to figure out things from debugger. If everyone was, number of questions here would reduce by 80%

Comment: @NathanOliver I would have closed this as "too broad". There are 5 separate questions here. Only one of them is a duplicate.

Comment: @melpomene I felt all the questions stemmed from them not knowing that pasing by value causes a copy.

Answer (score 1):

> Here for some reason default constructor is called. I don't see any place where we create object without parameter (aka that goes to default constructor)

I don't see any place either! How can you be so sure the default constructor is called? In fact, your class is not constructible using a default constructor because there isn't one. If you try this:

```
Line l;
```

It won't compile since there is no default constructor.

> Destructor is being called twice. Where is the second object is being created?

It this line:

```
display(line);
```

You function receives a value. To have a value both in your main and your display function, you have to copy it somehow. Passing `line` will copy it from your main to your function.

> Line::Line(const Line &obj) receives address of `a` as a parameter? I guess not. But why? a by itself is not an instance of Line, so why function accepts that?

No. This is a reference. The copy constructor receive a reference from other context to copy it.

> What would be the difference between `Line::Line(const Line &obj)` and `Line::Line(const Line obj)`

One is a reference, the other is passing by value (a copy, move or other construction). If the copy constructor had to receive a value, how would you copy the value into the copy constructor? The copy constructor must receive a reference.

> And could you please explain this *ptr = *obj.ptr; . From here i know only lhs, which dereferences ptr (aka sets value of an object). But I didn't get what's in rhs?

I don't know what you mean by `rhs` and `lhs`, is not in the code you posted. But indeed, `*ptr = *obj.ptr` will set the value from the integer pointed by `obj.ptr` into the variable pointed by `this->ptr`.

I recommend getting a good C++ book and follow a tutorial that will teach you the basics.